# How do I set up autoscaling on an IBM Cloud MongoDB database?

Tags: database, mongodb, cloud, ibm-cloud

I have an IBM Cloud MongoDB deployment. I can set up autoscaling in the UI, but I want to do script it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can set up autoscaling using the IBM Command Line Interface (CLI) `autoscaling` command.

You can install the CLI [from here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-install-ibmcloud-cli) and you will need to add the cloud databases plugin with:

```
ibmcloud plugin install cloud-databases
```

Log into the IBM Cloud CLI with:

```
ibmcloud login -sso
```

Follow the on-screen instructions to log in.

You can then list all the database deployments in your account with:

```
ibmcloud cdb ls

#Name                          Location   State
#Databases for PostgreSQL-76   us-south   inactive
#testelastic                   eu-gb      active
#Databases for MySQL-9j        us-south   active
#Databases for MongoDB-ky      eu-gb      active
```

You can list the current autoscaling setup for one of your databases by typing

```
ibmcloud cdb autoscaling "Databases for MongoDB-ky" member

I/O Utilization Scaler   Enabled   Over Period   Above Percent
Disk                     False     15m           90%
Memory                   False     15m           90%

Capacity Scaler   Enabled   Free Space Less Than
Disk              False     10%

Resource Rates   Increase Percent   Period Seconds   Limits per Member   Units
CPU              10.00%             900s             30.00               Count
Disk             10.00%             900s             3670016.00          MB
Memory           10.00%             900s             114688.00           MB
```

In order to set up RAM or Disk autoscaling, you have to define:

1. The conditions that have to be met before autoscaling occurs
2. The amount of resource scaling you want when the conditions are met.

In this example,

- you are scaling *disk* when there is less than 10% free disk space remaining *OR* when your IO utilization goes over 90% for more than 15 minutes. You will scale the disk by 10% every 15 minutes until you reach the disk ceiling.
- you are scaling *RAM* when IO utilization goes above 90% over a 15-minute period. You will scale the RAM by 10% every 15 minutes until you reach the RAM ceiling.

```
{
    "autoscaling": {
        "disk": {
            "scalers": {
                "capacity": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "free_space_less_than_percent": 10
                },
                "io_utilization": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "over_period": "15m",
                    "above_percent": 90
                }
            },
            "rate": {
                "increase_percent": 10,
                "period_seconds": 900,
                "limit_mb_per_member": 3670016,
                "units": "mb"
            }
        },
        "memory": {
            "scalers": {
                "io_utilization": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "over_period": "15m",
                    "above_percent": 90
                }
            },
            "rate": {
                "increase_percent": 10,
                "period_seconds": 900,
                "limit_mb_per_member": 114688,
                "units": "mb"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: Disk can only be scaled up, not down. If you want to scale RAM down, this has to be done via the UI.

You pass in the above as a JSON object to the CLI command:

```
ibmcloud cdb autoscaling-set "Databases for MongoDB-ky" member '{"autoscaling":{"disk":{"scalers":{"capacity":{"enabled":true,"free_space_less_than_percent":10},"io_utilization":{"enabled":true,"over_period":"15m","above_percent":90}},"rate":{"increase_percent":10,"period_seconds":900,"limit_mb_per_member":3670016,"units":"mb"}},"memory":{"scalers":{"io_utilization":{"enabled":true,"over_period":"15m","above_percent":90}},"rate":{"increase_percent":10,"period_seconds":900,"limit_mb_per_member":114688,"units":"mb"}}}}'

Setting autoscaling configuration for Databases for MongoDB-ky...
The deployment's autoscaling configuration is being changed with this task:

Key                   Value
ID                    <CRN>
Deployment ID         <CRN>
Description           Updating autoscale settings
Created At            2023-03-01T11:13:32Z
Status                running
Progress Percentage   0
                      
Status                completed
Progress Percentage   100
Location              <URL>
OK
```

For more information, see the [documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/databases-for-mongodb?topic=databases-for-mongodb-autoscaling&interface=cli)